# Grails controller service - src/groovy poll controller for property value

Tags: grails, websocket

I'm basically trying to get the percentage of time a task is taking to display to the user on the screen in an overlay template.

I have a service that is calculating the process percentage:

```
def progressCalculation(requestsToSend, requestsSent, requestsFailed, progressPercentage) {

   progressPercentage = 100 / requestsToSend * (requestsSent + requestsFailed)

   progressPercentage = Math.round(progressPercentage * 1) / 1

   MyController upCont = new MyController()
   upCont.progress(progressReport.progressPercentage)
}
```

this continues to send `progressReport.progressPercentage` to the controller:

```
def progress(progressData) {

    int statusToView = progressData

    if (statusToView % 5==0) {
        [statusToView: statusToView]
    }
}
```

I have created a src/groovy file that is using websockets from here: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-websocket-example/blob/master/README.md
My connection is working but I need to show the percentage on the view using the websocket which is working.

```
@OnMessage
public String handleMessage(String message) {

    message = MyController.progressPercentage

    String replyMessage = "echo "+message
    return replyMessage
}
```

now what I'm trying to so here is return the progressPercentage value from the controller to the src/groovy file so that my view can continually updated with the latest property value whilst the task is completing.

Answer (score 1):

`MyController upCont = new MyController()`  seriously?

It is good idea to move the code that hosts and modifies `progressPercentage` variable to service layer and access it using service rather than controller.

`myService.progressPercentage` rather than  `MyController.progressPercentage`

Also you must inject `myService` , not instantiate it as `myService = new MyService()`, services are singletons you can not instantiate them like this. They are managed by the [spring container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).

Actually if you do  `MyController upCont = new MyController()` 
and you try to access a property of `upCont` you will get this beautiful error message:

---

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

---

Comment: MyController is just for the purposes of on Stack Overflow.  I could change as you've suggest moving the progress calculation in to a service but then I still have the issue of getting that value to the src/groovy file which is what I'm struggling with. thanks

Comment: Yep you will need to move it to a service in order to interact with it via src/groovy. I will add on some more notes to my above answer to related to this comment

Answer (score 0):

I put those instructions together so if I can help you in any way do let me know.

Websockets require as much frontend work as backend. so to get back the data via websockets you need to expand on the java script as well as expand on the backend websocket sending that information to the java script.

So if you had a button on the frontend gsp that rather than was a typical

You can take a look at some of my plugins that already do this. There is a ping/pong that happens discretely in https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh  which if user defines within taglib the websocket connection triggers a pong that frontend javascript receives and sends ping - and they continue doing this..

Here is another example which is what you probably need to use:

This is the result back from websocket

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/jen/_process.gsp#L411

which when recieved updates this span or div id:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/jen/_process.gsp#L213

so you need to get your websocket to send it back in some json format that your frontend javascript picks up the json request and if it is of a certain convention to look for a value and update a div on the frontend.

There is a good video I have done on wschat which shows you updating frontend using websocket client/server. it may help you understand it better

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xagMYM9n3l0 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAySkzNid3E
unsure which one it was in

E2A: it will need to be a service:

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/WsChatEndpoint.groovy#L63 then the few lines ahead registers those services in the websocket endpoint. Now going back in the history of the code or if you follow onMessage to verifyAction - you will need to send something from frontend - or upon when a connection is made to then send a message to frontend https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/75590bf10ea040c18548377dedc716fdab2aa820/src/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/WsChatEndpoint.groovy#L148. You can use userSession to directly message the person making the socket connection. On webpage using javascript parse json and update div as mentioned above